# How to go from linker error to line of code in the sources?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, linker, g++

The linker produces this kind of output

```
/var/tmp/ccITB4j2.o: In function `main':
/var/tmp/ccITB4j2.o(.text+0x4): undefined reference to `myFunction(void)'
```

How can I find out the line of source code corresponding to the instruction at .text+0x4 where the function is actually invoked?

Comment: It already tells you that `main()` is invoking the function.  What good is knowing the line number going to do?  It's not like it's a syntax problem where seeing the specific call site matters.

Comment: I'm not sure the linker knows about the line numbers in source code

Comment: both objections are valid, but the question remains. If I wanted, how would one do?

Comment: @jamesdlin: also note that gdb does it, so it must have a way of doing something similar.

Comment: The best way to get the line number is to use find dialog of your editor and search for `myFunction(`. All you find are errors.

Comment: @stardust_: gdb can tell the match between section offset and the generating source code, and I doubt it uses grep.

Comment: @Lothar_K: question not answered. I don't give a damn about why the linker does not evaluate debugging info. I want to know how to find out the source line from the section offset as given by the linker, something that gdb does, but I don't know how. If I did, I would have not asked the question.

Answer (score 5):

First, the other answer to your question is wrong: on Linux you *do* get file and line number from the linker:

```
$ cat foo.cc
extern int myFunction(void);

int main()
{
  return myFunction();
}
$ g++ -g foo.cc
/tmp/cc3twlhL.o: In function `main':
/tmp/foo.cc:5: undefined reference to `myFunction()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Above output is from `gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3` and linker `GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.22`, but this has been true for much older versions of GCC and ld as well.

The reason you are not getting the file/line must be that

- you didn't use `-g` flag, or
- you have a *really* old `ld`, or
- you have configured your `ld` without support for debugging (I am not sure this is even possible).

However, even if your `ld` is refusing to tell you the file and line, not all is lost. You can compile your source into object, then use `objdump -rdS foo.o` to obtain the same info:

```
g++ -g -c foo.cc
objdump -rdS foo.o

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <main>:
extern int myFunction(void);

int main()
{
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  return myFunction();
   4:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  9 <main+0x9>
            5: R_X86_64_PC32    _Z10myFunctionv-0x4
}
   9:   5d                      pop    %rbp
   a:   c3                      retq
```

In above output, you can clearly see which source line caused reference to `_Z10myFunctionv` (which is the `C++` mangled name for `myFunction(void)`) to be emitted in the object file.

Answer (score 2):

Key to understanding linker errors is to know the difference between a declaration and a definition.

This is a declaration:

```
int myFunction();
```

This is a definition:

```
int myFunction() {
  // do something
  return val;
}
```

When you declare something, the compiler takes it as a promise from you, that you will eventually define it also (perhaps later in the same translation unit, or maybe in a different one). These promises are actually checked by the linker at link time.

So a linker error (such as this one) is actually complaining that you broke your promise to define something. Since this happens after compilation, and since this deals with something that is "not there", it is meaningless to ask for "the line number where it is not there".

Hope that helps explain why you wont get a line number tacked onto an "unresolved symbol" error message from the linker.

Comment: to emit that line, myFunction has been called at some point. The fact that is not defined takes nothing from the fact that there's a point in the source where that function is invoked.

Comment: The word "never" is too strong. Maybe a compiler can show the line number at least in debug mode in future.

Comment: Fair enough, the compiler *can* accumulate line numbers where every function is called into the .o (for debug mode). That way, the linker would have something to go on. AFAIK, gcc does not do this.

Comment: Firstly gdb is not a linker. When code is compiled with the -g flag, the ELF generated has debugging information (in DWARF format, I believe) inside it. The .debug_info section maps a function name to its location (machine code offset) in the generated binary. Obviously, if the linker failed to resolve (locate) the code for a function, this information would be missing. Thus, for an unresolved function, this will not help a linker pin-point the "line number".

Comment: @RahulBanerjee: This is a bit more helpful. So the next question is: if debug_info is provided by the compiler (because it's the one that sees the source and the object file) why wouldn't it be present on the object file at linking time ?

Comment: Glad I could help. Strictly speaking, there's no reason why this should be "impossible". The compiler can copiously annotate the object and the linker could then be a lot smarter about what it spews when it cannot resolve a symbol. However, that's not the case with gcc or ld.

Comment: This answer is *plain wrong*: "you'll never get a line number tacked onto an error message from the linker." is false.

Comment: Noted, and clarified. Your answer below is also helpful (using `objdump`). Thanks!

Comment: @StefanoBorini, in response to your question about debug_info: if you use a tool such as `objdump` and don't see a `debug_line` section, then I don't think the source:line info isn't present.

Answer (score 1):

I have 3 answers (so far), and an analysis about a particular case where I needed to know how to do this

---

`addr2line` can do it, provided the compiler generated debugging information compatible with the tool.

```
~ cat asdf.txt
/var/tmp/ccITB4j2.o: In function `main':
/var/tmp/ccITB4j2.o(.text+0x4): undefined reference to `myFunction(void)'
~ cat asdf.txt | addr2line -e /var/tmp/ccITB4j2.o
... it should print src:line info here
```

---

Then there's `objdump`:

```
objdump --dwarf=decodedline test.o
test.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

Decoded dump of debug contents of section .debug_line:

CU: test.cc:
File name                           Line number     Starting address
test.cc                                       2                 0x23
test.cc                                       3                 0x84
```

---

In answer to the question "how does the debugger do it", here's a nice article on the topic: [How debuggers work: Part 3 - Debugging information](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/02/07/how-debuggers-work-part-3-debugging-information), which is where the `objdump` option came from.

I'll apologize in advance for future generations if the link breaks.

---

I ran into a problem along these lines with Solaris Studio 12.3 in Linux.  It looks as though the information it generates (whether in `.debug_line` or some other section) debug information incompatible with `addr2line`, but only when built with optimizations.  The following code will induce a similar link error:

```
~ cat test.cc
struct Test {int x; Test(); };
inline void test() { Test *t = new Test(); }
void blah() { test(); }
~ CC -g -Kpic test.cc -shared -o libtest.so -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-shared-libs
(...)
test.cc:2: undefined reference to `void operator delete(void*)'
(...)
~ CC -g -Kpic test.cc -shared -o libtest.so -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-shared-libs -O0
(...)
test.cc:(.text+0x45): undefined reference to `void operator delete(void*)'
(...)
~ CC -g -Kpic test.cc     -c
~ addr2line -e test.o +0x45
test.cc:2
~ CC -g -Kpic test.cc -O0 -c
~ addr2line -e test.o +0x45
??:?
```

Resolving the link error for that case requires linking against a compiler library `libCrun`.  As a counter-example to the naysayer comments about it being useless to know the line numbers: it certainly had me scratching my head as to where the `delete` was being referenced.  As it turns out, the compiler is inserting extra code that allocates stuff & deletes it.  Had it correctly printed the line number (the close brace of the function) it would've been far more obvious that the compiler was doing something out of the ordinary.