# Find sourcecode line which causes undefined reference error

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, g++

sooner or later when programming in C/C++ everyone will face the "undefined reference error".

Often this is caused by missing libraries and most of those errors are fixed within seconds by linking against the missing libraries.
However, when for instance one uses templates with seperate files for declaration and implementation, one may get undefined reference caused by "unintended" template instantiation. Unfortunately, all information we now get is an instance of "undefined reference error", without possible hints for the cause such as line numbers of the callers, etc.

What I am curious about: 
Is there an easy way to spot the actual sourcecode line(s) that calls the function/the template causing the undefined reference error?

Comment: It typically gives the name of the function, and as long as it's called something reasonably unique, you can use `grep -n` to get a line number... But if you have 400 functions called `size()` that may not help much...

Comment: Isn't it just a matter of demangling the name of the symbol? BUt I guess it depends on what you mean by this mystical "C/C++".

Comment: Just `grep` the file for the undefined identifier.

Comment: Just saying use grep to find the function is not a solution. A scope resolution operator could have been left off causing a member function to be undefined, A file might not be included correcting in the makefile/project, the proper compiler specific export may not have been included, an extern may have been left out, or the linked item may be in C code referenced from C++ and the C from extern c may have been left out. Grep finds maybe a few of these, but it by no means finds all. and not all systems with GCC have grep. The real question here is about troubleshooting the tricky cases.

Comment: It is not only a problem of demangling, see instantiated templates for example, which might be symbols hard to spot in the original sourcecode.

One probably might use tools like grep or general "find [XYZ] in files" to spot the error. 

I was just curious if there is way to get the compiler/linker toolchain to hint me into the right direction rather than doing it all myself. Maybe it is impossible due to a seperation of compiler and linker tools and steps, but theoretically it should be possible for the toolchain to give some more informative messages.

Comment: Found that there is a somehow similar question with matching answers:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15889650/how-to-go-from-linker-error-to-line-of-code-in-the-sources?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I mentioned in my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15889650/how-to-go-from-linker-error-to-line-of-code-in-the-sources?rq=1), whether or not it's straightforward to get a line number causing the link error depends on whether the compiler emitted all the necessary information.

To begin with, these are the cases I've run into that lead to the behavior you're seeing:

- The compiler emitting faulty debug info (solaris studio 12.3 with debugging/optimizations under certain circumstances)
- A destructor executing for an object going out of scope
- Code inserted by the compiler:

  - stack protector
  - sanitizers
  - other tools that instrument code either for debugging or profiling

---

What I'll suggest for tracking it down may help if you have a link error resembling:

```
asdf.o: In function `whatever':
asdf.o(.text+0x1238): undefined reference to `fdsa'
```

... because at the very least you have an address to work with.

First, try `addr2line`:

```
~ addr2line -e asdf.o 0x1238
# If it works, you'll get:
asdf.cc:N
# If it doesn't work, you'll get:
??:?
```

Failing that, try `objdump`:

```
~ objdump --dwarf=decodedline asdf.o

asdf.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

Decoded dump of debug contents of section .debug_line:

CU: asdf.cc:
File name                           Line number     Starting address
asdf.cc                                       1               0x1234
asdf.cc                                       3               0x1254
asdf.cc                                       5               0x1274
```

In the completely fabricated example I've given here there isn't an entry in `.debug_line` corresponding to `0x1238` (the address in the linker error), so it could be compiler magic (eg extra code added by something like stack protector or a sanitizer), or hopefully it's related to whatever is happening on lines 1/3 since the address is between those two lines.

If that doesn't give you enough to go on: when I wanted a little more to go on I did the following:

1. Insert a link flag to stop it from demangling to get the mangled symbol
2. Recompile the object file, but have it generate assembly instead
3. Search the assembly for the mangled symbol

Assuming the assembly is annotated well enough it shouldn't be terribly hard to correlate the missing symbol + info from `objdump` + the assembly and at least get a fix on the line of code to start the rest of your search (assuming you still have more rabbit holes to go down as is often the case with STL).